# Webstorm appearance scheme

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I was used to work on Webstorm normally , but i'm getting suddenly 2 problems :

1. in the console i'm not able to see what i write , it seems like that what i'm writing is getting transparent.

   2.i'm not finding the default white scheme (white)

I have tried to switch on schemes , but right now i'm not able to set Webstorm to the "white" theme which i prefer.

The following screenshots may give you an idea:

Here the problem with the transparent console :
[image]

and that's the general ugly appearence colors :
[image]

How may i get back the white appearance ; you should know that switching the schemes colors doesn't resolve the problem , and the the colors switching have always had effect only on the part of the console.

**ideas ( except re-installing the whole IDE) ?**

Answer (score 0):

1. please try a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552#comment=27-1048994 - does it help?
2. try switching the IDE theme to `Intellij` in `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance, Theme`; if prompted, make sure to also switch the editor scheme accordingly (to `Default`)

Comment: it seems that there is a probleme in resizing the IDE and the dimensions of the screened

Comment: i solved the problem by randomly resize to smaller the Webstrom windows and the terminal part of the screen